# How to intercept HTTP requests on Linux desktops?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I really appreciate if someone could give me an idea how to implement this. Also, is it possible to have a common implementation for most of the popular Linux desktop distros, if not all of them. Thanks.

What I need to implement is something like a Windows service, which runs automatically every time the OS boots. What it does is to intercept all HTTP requests made from browsers and record the request url. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: huh.. What? Please explain more thoroughly, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: When you say "implement", are you trying write your own tool to intercept the traffic? If you are looking for pre-built solution, as @Kaleb Pederson mentioned, tcpdump is the best tool out there (hint:  tcpdump port 80)

Comment: Thanks. My bad if the question is not clear. What I need to implement is something like a Windows service, which runs automatically every time the OS boots. What it does is to intercept all HTTP requests made from browsers and record the request url. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: The first question that pops to my mind is 'why'? At least in Europe, doing something like this is downright illegal - unless you track only your OWN usage...

Comment: Besides the legal concerns raised by @Kimvais, you still need to better define your requirements, such as: Linux distro, what browser & version, language choice, and other concerns such as whether if any running daemon drop inbound/outbound http requests etc. You got the picture

Comment: @Kimvais - There is no legal issue for our case. We already have such a client application that runs on Windows, and of course, the user is clearly aware that the client is going to track his http requests before he downloads/installs our client. We are not one of those who create malware/spyware, :-).

Comment: @Jay - Forgive my limited knowledge on Linux distros. We are trying to port our Windows client to Linux desktops, so it would be nice that if we can find a common solution that covers all popular Linux desktop distros, or at least most of them. Since all Linux distros are based on the same kernel, can we make this happen at the kernel level?

If we program at the system level, i.e. it intercepts all http request, it wouldn't matter what browser/language it is, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a [transparent proxy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html).

Comment: +1. I think this will work better for you than the solutions in Kaleb's answer which are more like development tools rather than long running services.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is the right answer for me.

Two concerns:
1. How much impact does it have on the performance of user desktop? 
2. Will this work for all the popular Linux desktop distros?

Comment: It will cause a short delay as the proxy processes (you don't need to use squid; any program that can act as an HTTP proxy will work), but it will work on all Linux distros from about the past... 4 years or so.

Comment: On further reading of the doc, it turned out that for a transparent proxy to work, you may need recompile the kernel and set up squid, which unfortunately can't happen in my case. Is there another way of intercepting http request without recompiling kernel and/or set up a 3rd party software?

Comment: All kernels short of a badly-mutilated Gentoo or scratch kernel have the necessary support already compiled in. And you don't need to use squid; any app that can act as a HTTP proxy, even one you write yourself, will work.

Comment: The best way is not to put it on the desktops, but to put it in the path to the network.  That way it'll work for *anything* that uses HTTP in the network, regardless of OS, and it can't be tinkered with locally.

Answer (score 4):

I have a few favorites depending on what I'm trying to accomplish.  They are:

1. [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/) - It's perfect for commandline output to console when you just need a quick idea of what's going on.
2. [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) - When I'm on a box that doesn't have X windows running, I just output to a file and then can use a GUI program to view the output file.
3. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - a full-blown GUI that allows you to do almost anything you want with your output.